# I get an error when calling a textbox from form1

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2015

I'm having issues with this:

I have this code on `Form2`:

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lbl0, lbl1, lbl11, lbl2, lbl22, lbl3, lbl33, lbl4, lbl44, lbl5, lbl55, lbl6, lbl66, lbl7, lbl77 As New Label
    lbl0.Text = "ACCESORIOS"
    lbl0.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("MS Reference Sans Serif", 15.75, FontStyle.Bold)
    lbl0.Location = New Point(110, 12)
    lbl0.AutoSize = True
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl0)
    lbl1.Text = "Té 180°"
    lbl11.Text = Te180
    lbl2.Text = "Té 90° Empalme - Codo Triple"
    If form1.TextBox3.Text <> 0 Then
        lbl22.Text = 0
    Else
        lbl22.Text = (Int(form1.TextBox1.Text) + Int(form1.TextBox2.Text)) - 1
    End If
    lbl3.Text = "Soporte 90° T/T"
    lbl33.Text = SoporteTT90
    TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl33, 0, 0)
End Sub
End Class
```

Don't mind the variables not used, or the single tablelayoutpannel adding, since it's a work in progress. Anyway, this code works well the first time I run it, but when I press reset,

which is a button in form1 that contains this piece of code:

```
    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim frm = New form1
    frm.Show()
    Me.Close()
    Te180 = 0
    ContadorGlobal = 0
    SoporteTT90 = 0
    End Sub
```

I end up with this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>       Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I get that when the program goes through here:

```
If form1.TextBox3.Text <> 0 Then
    lbl22.Text = 0
Else
    lbl22.Text = (Int(form1.TextBox1.Text) + Int(form1.TextBox2.Text)) - 1
End If
```

Any help is appreciated. Many I'm not calling form1.textbox1.text correctly. Maybe I'm not resetting it properly. I have no idea since I'm not an expert. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Text property of Textboxes and Labels are of type String.

Assuming that `form1.TextBox1.Text` and `form1.TextBox2.Text` contains integer values, you're setting an arithmethic operation result to `lbl22.Text` which should contain a string, not a number.

Change

```
lbl22.Text = (Int(form1.TextBox1.Text) + Int(form1.TextBox2.Text)) - 1
```

By

```
lbl22.Text = ((Int(form1.TextBox1.Text) + Int(form1.TextBox2.Text)) - 1).ToString
```

Said that, the error `Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid` is telling you that an empty string cannot be converted to a number, so be sure both `TextBox1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text` are not empty prior to perform the arithmetic operation.

Comment: That didn't work :/. I get this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and it points that the error is here:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     If form1.TextBox3.Text <> 0 Then
    lbl22.Text = 0
    Else
    lbl22.Text = (Int(form1.TextBox1.Text) + Int(form1.TextBox2.Text)) - 1
    End If

Comment: Also, like I said. It works the first time I run it, is after I press the reset button that it doesn't work :/

Comment: That's why the first time both `TextBox1.Text` and `TextBox2.Text` has value. I bet the second time at least one of them has lost its value and it's empty.

Comment: Furthermore, when you're clicking the `Reset` button your creating a new instance of `Form1`, so `form1.TextBox1.Text` and `form1.TextBox2.Text` wil be empty.

Comment: Oh, ok. Thank you. I ended up creating global variables that get the value of textbox1.text and textbox2.text in form1. So it doesn't matter if it's a new form or not, it grabs the value and then the code in form2 works everytime. Thanks for your help though!